# Error when inserting an invalid input

Tags: c, visual-c++, null, strtok

The expected input is : SET_MINE X Y, while X and Y have to be numbers between 0-19; when the  user finishes inserting his data he is expected to write SET_DONE.
I'm facing two problems here, which apparently happen due to the same reason:
1. when I insert : SET_MINE (and then press ENTER) or SET_MINE X (inserting only one number rather than two), the line "Insert failed: not enough parameters" is printed on the screen an infinite number of times!
2. The exact same thing happens when I insert numbers out of the range [0,19], e.g: SET_MINE 56 7.Here I'm expecting to see this line on the screen "Insert failed: illegal row/col", but instead I get this one: "Insert failed: not enough parameters" printed an infinite number of times.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
int game_board[FIELD_ROWS][FIELD_COLS]={0};
char szLine[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
char* delimiters = " \t\n";
char* pszCommand;
char* pszCol;
char* pszRow;

BOOL gameContinue= TRUE;
MINE* pHead = NULL;
POSITION pos;

int stepDirection;
int row=0;
int col=0;
int old_row=row, old_col=col, mine=0;

fgets(szLine,MAX_LINE_SIZE,stdin);      // get line from standard input
while (strncmp(szLine,"SET_DONE",8) != 0)
{
    pszCommand = strtok(szLine, delimiters);

    if (NULL == pszCommand )
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (0 == strcmp(pszCommand, "SET_MINE"))
    {
        pszRow = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        pszCol = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        if (NULL == pszCol || NULL == pszRow)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Insert failed: not enough parameters\n");
            continue;
        }
        row = atoi(pszRow);
        col = atoi(pszCol);
        if (row <0 || row >= FIELD_ROWS || col < 0 || col >= FIELD_COLS)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Insert failed: illegal row/col \n");
            continue;
        }

            game_board[row][col]=-1; // a mine is inserted to this place
    }

    fgets(szLine,MAX_LINE_SIZE,stdin); // get line from standard input
}
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `continue` so your second `fgets` is never executed. See the standard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3dc2z3.aspx (Microsoft's site, but still applicable)

Think of the `continue` statement like telling the loop "Okay, this iteration is done, start the next one."

So when you reach the part where you tell the user they didn't supply enough parameters, this is all that the loop sees:

```
fgets(szLine,MAX_LINE_SIZE,stdin);      // get line from standard input
while (strncmp(szLine,"SET_DONE",8) != 0)
{
   ...;
   if (0 == strcmp(pszCommand, "SET_MINE"))
   {
        pszRow = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        pszCol = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        if (NULL == pszCol || NULL == pszRow)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Insert failed: not enough parameters\n");
            continue;
        }
   }
   //nothing down here
}
```

In the eyes of the program, the second `fgets` at the bottom of the loop doesn't exist.

You can fix this by using more clever conditional logic.

This (untested) code snippet should fix things:

```
while (strncmp(szLine,"SET_DONE",8) != 0)
{
    pszCommand = strtok(szLine, delimiters);

    if (pszCommand != NULL && 0 == strcmp(pszCommand, "SET_MINE"))
    {
        pszRow = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        pszCol = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        if (NULL != pszCol && NULL != pszRow)
        {
            row = atoi(pszRow);
            col = atoi(pszCol);
            if (row < 0 || row >= FIELD_ROWS || col < 0 || col >= FIELD_COLS)
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "Insert failed: illegal row/col \n");
            }
            else
            {
               game_board[row][col]=-1; // a mine is inserted to this place
            }
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Insert failed: not enough parameters\n");
        }

    }

    fgets(szLine,MAX_LINE_SIZE,stdin); // get line from standard input
}
```

Comment: That really works; also, I tried "do-while" , and wrote "fgets" at the beginning of the loop only, that also works.